# awk: extract ips occurrences with higher date

Tags: date, awk, text-parsing

I need to extract just a few data from Apache's access.log and I tried with awk command
I need to list all IPs, ordered by the number of times they appear (in descending order) with the time the request was received closer to current one.

the pattern of access.log is as follow

```
LogFormat "%h %t \"%!200,304,302r\" %>s %O \"%!200,304,302{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

which produces

```
192.168.0.147 [08/Aug/2016:10:55:14 +0200] "GET /requestPath/ HTTP/1.1" 401 1638 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```

I was only able to produce this script

```
awk '{print $1}' /var/log/apache2/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -fr
```

but I do not now how to extract the date

to be more clear 
access.log

```
192.168.0.147 [01/Aug/2016:10:55:14 +0000] ...
192.168.0.147 [02/Aug/2016:10:55:14 +0000] ... 
192.168.0.147 [02/Aug/2016:11:55:14 +0000] ...
192.168.0.122 [08/Aug/2016:10:15:11 +0000] ...
```

desired output

```
3 192.168.0.147 02/Aug/2016:11:55:14
1 192.168.0.122 08/Aug/2016:10:15:11
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^\[/,"",$2); a[$1]=$2;c[$1]++} END {for(i in a) print c[i],i,a[i]}' c
3 192.168.0.147 02/Aug/2016:11:55:14
1 192.168.0.122 08/Aug/2016:10:15:11
```

The date is the date of the last record of each particular IP.

```
{
    sub(/^\[/,"",$2) # remove [
    a[$1]=$1" "$2    # each ip gets it's own array element where last record is stored
    c[$1]++}         # ips are counted
END {
    for(i in a)      # print count and last record
        print c[i],i,a[i]
}
```

Comment: You seem to assume whitespace between the date and time, but it's all in a single field in the OP's sample.

Comment: No I didn't. I was going to leave the time zone but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanx James, it works well, but it is an unordered list. What if I need to have the results ordered by the number of times ips appear (in descending order)?

Comment: Well the easiest way would be to redirect the output of above command to `sort`: `awk ... | sort -n -r` (`-n`numeric sort, `-r` reverse order).

Answer (score 0):

Collect the IP addresses into a hash; replace the value every time you see a new match; then at the end, print out the hash.

```
awk -F '[ [\t]+' '{ d[$1] = $2 } END { for (i in d) print i, d[i] }' access.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments; typo fixed.

Comment: @lnian Yeah, you could include a simple `sub` or change the `FS` to fix that. I added an `-F` option now.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"[] []" '{a[$1]++;b[$1]=$3} END{for ( i in a) print a[i],i,b[i]}' access.log
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

No need to store the whole file in memory:

```
$ awk -F'[[ ]+' '$1!=p{ if (NR>1) print c, p, t; c=0} {c++; p=$1; t=$2} END{print c, p, t}' access.log
3 192.168.0.147 02/Aug/2016:11:55:14
1 192.168.0.122 08/Aug/2016:10:15:11
```